# Unable to get page source code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I'm trying to get the source code of a page by using:

```
import urllib2
url="http://france.meteofrance.com/france/meteo?PREVISIONS_PORTLET.path=previsionsville/750560"
page =urllib2.urlopen(url)
data=page.read()
print data
```

and also by using a `user_agent(headers)` 
I did not succeed to get the source code of the page!

Have you guys any ideas what can be done?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the issue? That seems to work for me.

Comment: Works for me too. Is your internet on?

Comment: What your getting is not the complete source code! try to open the page you will see the difference

Comment: it seems that is there a hidden input in the page

<input name="t:ac" type="hidden" value=...

Answer (score 11):

I tried it and the requests works, but the content that you receive says that your browser must accept cookies (in french). You could probably get around that with `urllib2`, but I think the easiest way would be to use the `requests` lib (if you don't mind having an additional dependency).

To install `requests`:

```
pip install requests
```

And then in your script:

```
import requests

url = 'http://france.meteofrance.com/france/meteo?PREVISIONS_PORTLET.path=previsionsville/750560'

response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

I'm pretty sure the source code of the page will be what you expect then.

Answer (score 2):

`requests` library worked for me as [Martin Maillard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193366/martin-maillard) showed.

Also in another thread I have noticed this note by [leoluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363811/leoluk) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533528/python-web-crawlers-and-getting-html-source-code):

> Edit: It's 2014 now, and most of the important libraries have been
>   ported and you should definitely use Python 3 if you can.
>   python-requests is a very nice high-level library which is easier to
>   use than urllib2.

So I wrote this get_page procedure:

```
import requests
def get_page (website_url):
    response = requests.get(website_url)
    return response.content

print get_page('http://example.com')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things, "urllib" "urllib2" and many other things, but one thing worked for me for everything I needed and solved any problem I faced. It was [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) .This library simulates using a real browser, so it handles a lot of issues in that area.