# python requests cannot get html

Tags: python

I tried to get html code from a site name dcinside in Korea, i am using requests but cannot get html code

and this is my code

```
import requests
url = "http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=bitcoins&page=1"
req = requests.get(url)
print (req)
print (req.content)
```

but the result was

[image]

Why I cannot get html codes even using requests??

Answer (score 5):

Most likely they are detecting that you are trying to crawl data dynamically, and not giving any content as a response. Try pretending to be a browser and passing some `User-Agent` headers.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0', 
    'From': 'youremail@domain.com'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# use authentic mozilla or chrome user-agent strings if this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

1. [Python Web Crawlers and "getting" html source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533528/python-web-crawlers-and-getting-html-source-code)

Like the guy said in the aforementioned post, you should use `urllib2` which will allow you to easily obtain web resources.

Comment: using `urllib2` does not seem to be working with the website OP wants to fetch.